# It just adds on

Tags: java

So for yet ANOTHER project I am doing an RPG code. Like Dungeons and dragons. My particular problem is the attributes. Basically the application gives statistics to the player and then, in case the player does not like the stats they have recieved, the application gives them the option to reroll. The first roll does fine, however, if the user chooses to reroll, the stats (both the first and the next) add on to each other. Here is my code:

The Main Method:

```
   package bagOfHolding;

    public class Advanced {
    public static void main(String [] args){
    GameMaster.game();

    }
    }

The Dice Class (this rolls the stats for the statistics):

package bagOfHolding;

import java.util.Random;

public class DiceBag {
    private static int sum;

    public static int rollD6() {
        int[] Dice = new int[3];
        Random num = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < Dice.length; i++) {
            Dice[i] = num.nextInt((6)) + 1;
        }

        for (int i : Dice) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    // public static int getSum() {
    // return sum;
    // }
    // public static void setSum(int sum) {
    // DiceBag.sum = sum;
    // }
}
```

The Game Master (This does the whole game):

```
package bagOfHolding;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GameMaster {
    public static void game() {
        Hero.attributes();
    }

    public static void ReRoll() {
        BufferedReader delta = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Would you like to reroll your hero? 1) Yes or 2) No");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        System.out.println("Any number other than 1 or 2 will exit the application");
        try {
            String userInput = delta.readLine();
            int input = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
            if (input == 1) {
                Hero.setStrength(DiceBag.rollD6());
                Hero.setDexterity(DiceBag.rollD6());
                Hero.setIntelligence(DiceBag.rollD6());
                Hero.attributes();
            } else if (input == 2) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException NFE) {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        } catch (IOException IOE) {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

And the Hero class (this has all the statistics):

```
package bagOfHolding;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Hero {
    /*
     * Attributes - Randomly determined by 3d6
     * 
     */
    /*
     * -3 attributes - Strength - Damage bonus - If over 15 every pt = +1 (_++;)
     * - Negative Damage Bonus - If under 10 every pt = -1 (_--;) - Dexterity
     * -Strike bonus - every 2 pts over 14 = (_%2 + 1) - Negative Strike bonus -
     * every 2 pts below 10 = (_%2 -1) - Dodge bonus - every 2 pts over 15 =
     * (_%2 + 1) - Negative dodge bonus - every 2 pts below 11 = (_%2 -1) -
     * Intelligence -Spell Strength Bonus - every pt over 15 = (++2) - Negative
     * Spell Strength Bonus - every pt below 11 = (--2)
     * 
     * Base Attributes - Health -Strength * 10 - MP - Intelligence *5
     */
    private static int strength = DiceBag.rollD6();
    private static int intelligence = DiceBag.rollD6();
    private static int dexterity = DiceBag.rollD6();

    public static int getIntelligence() {
        return intelligence;
    }

    public static void setIntelligence(int intelligence) {
        Hero.intelligence = intelligence;
    }

    public static int getDexterity() {
        return dexterity;
    }

    public static void setDexterity(int dexterity) {
        Hero.dexterity = dexterity;
    }

    public static int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    public static void setStrength(int strength) {
        Hero.strength = strength;
    }

    public static void attributes() {
        strength = getStrength();
        System.out.println("Here is your hero: ");
        // DiceBag.rollD6();
        System.out.println("Strength = " + strength);
        if (strength > 15) {
            System.out.println("Damage Bonus = " + "+" + (strength - 15));
        } else if (strength < 10) {
            System.out.println("Negative Damage Bonus = " + "-" + (10 - strength));
        } else {
            System.out.println("You do not have damage bonus");
        }

        intelligence = getIntelligence();
        System.out.println("Intelligence = " + intelligence);
        if (intelligence > 15) {
            System.out.println("Spell Strength Bonus = " + "+" + ((intelligence - 15) * 2));
        } else if (strength < 11) {
            System.out.println("Negative Spell Strength Bonus = " + "-" + ((11 - intelligence) * 2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("You do not have a spell strength bonus");
        }

        dexterity = getDexterity();
        System.out.println("Dexterity = " + dexterity);
        if (dexterity > 15 && dexterity % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Dodge Bonus = " + "+" + (dexterity - 15));
        } else if (dexterity < 11 && dexterity % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Negative Dodge Bonus = " + "-" + (11 - dexterity));
        } else {
            System.out.println("You do not have a dodge bonus");
        }
        if (dexterity > 14 && dexterity % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Strike Bonus = " + "+" + (dexterity - 14));
        } else if (dexterity < 10 && dexterity % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Negative Strike bonus = " + "-" + (10 - dexterity));
        } else {
            System.out.println("You do not have a strike bonus");
        }

        int health = strength * 10;
        System.out.println("Health = " + health);

        int MP = intelligence * 5;
        System.out.println("MP = " + MP);

        GameMaster.ReRoll();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is on awful title and a large blob of code, maybe go over [MCVE] and come up with a better title.

Comment: The fact that it is adding should help point you in the right direction. That's a ton of code to just dump. Check your process for setting stats with a debugger so you can see variable values. Somewhere, you are retaining the previous value. Personally, I would Would add either xyz.reset() to reset the stats, and then reroll them as you did. (I'm on mobile now and cannot get to my dev machine for a few days. Once I do I'll try finding you an exact solution if it's still needed.)

Answer (score 0):

DiceBag sum should be local to rollD6 rather than static.